# Proof verification of a problem of Riemann Integration

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, riemann-integration

> **[ISI M.Math 2016, PMB, Group A]** Suppose $f : [0,1] →\mathbb R$ is a bounded function such that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,1]$ for every $a ∈ (0,1)$. Is $f$ Riemann integrable on $[0, 1]$ ? Justify your answer.

My attempt :

Consider a sequence ${{a_n}}_n$ from $[0,1]$ which converges to $0$. Since $0 \notin {{a_n}}_n$, $f$ is Riemann integrable in $[a_n,1]$ $\forall n \in \mathbb N$. Now, since $f$ is bounded in $[0,1]$, there is only one case of improper integration, i.e., having uncountable points on discontinuity in domain. Since $f$ is integrable in $[a_n,1]$, there is countable points of discontinuity. Let the set be $S_n$. Consider $\cup S_n = S$ and the set of all points of discontinuity of $f$ in $[0,1]$ is $B$. Then, $S \subseteq B$. Let a point $c \in B$ such that $c \notin S$. Since $c \in [0,1]$, we will find an $a_k$ (by Archimedean property) such that $a_k \leq c$. Then $c \in [a_k,1]$, which implies $S = B$, and hence the result.

I'm not convinced if there is any fault in my proofline. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The weak point of your proof is:"Since $f$ is integrable in $[a_n,1]$, there is countable points of discontinuity." This implication is only true if $f$ is monotonic or $BV$. The basic theorem of Riemann's integration theory states that: $f$ is $R$-integrable $\iff$ its set of discontinuity points is a zero measure set.

Comment: Yes, but if $f$ is not Riemann integrable in its domain, then either $f$ is unbounded in domain, or has uncountably many points of discontinuity, right ?? @ Daniele Tampieri

Comment: I am not sure about the boundedness: I do not remember exactly, but It seems to me that there are counterexamples not relying on it but only on the measure of the set of singular points. I should check this.

Comment: Use Darboux criteria for upper lower sums.

Comment: It is not "uncountably many points of discontinuity", but is "the set of discontinuity is not of measure zero".

Comment: If you wanted to argue via points of discontinuity, you could prove that, since the set $D_n$ of discontinuities in $[a_n, 1]$ is null, the countable union $\cup_n D_n$ is null as well, and so the discontinuities on $[0, 1]$ are a null set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to argue via points of discontinuity. One can proceed using Darboux sums.

---

Let $\epsilon >0$ be arbitrary. If $M>0$ is a bound for $|f|$ then split the interval $[0,1]$ into $[0,a]$ and $[a, 1]$ where $a=\min(\epsilon/4M,1)$. Since $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, 1]$ there is a partition $P'$ of $[a, 1]$ with $$U(P', f) - L(P', f)<\frac{\epsilon} {2} $$ Let $P=P'\cup \{0\}$ and then $P$ is a partition of $[0,1]$ and we have $$U(P, f) - L(P, f) < 2M\cdot\frac{\epsilon} {4M}+\frac{\epsilon} {2}=\epsilon $$ and therefore $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.